# How can I connect the RCX 2.0 to an external power source?

Tags: mindstorms, rcx

I want to build an auto-feeder with the RCX 2.0 for my cat. The problem is, that I often had to exchange the batteries. Is there an adapter for the RCX to connect it to a power point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The older RCX 1.0 had a power plug inbuilt. However Philo has shown how to create one yourself in a fairly simple way:
[LEGO® 9V Technic Motors compared characteristics](http://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm), scroll down to the section "Getting maximum mechanical power from RCX output" towards the bottom of the page.

The idea is to create two fake batteries and draw a wire from each, creating a +9V and a ground from a separate source. You would need a voltage regulator though. **WARNING**: supplying incorrect voltage can destroy your RCX.
[image: Using fake batteries to power the RCX]

Image and technique by Philippe "Philo" Hurbain © 2000-2009, used in accordance to "You are free to use it for any purpose, just give me credit...".

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not cut off the ends off two batteries and jury-rig in rods of hot melting glue to act as spacers, and instead have access to a 3D printer, take a look at http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:122810 :-)

---

As the contents of the linked page have been removed, here are the original files:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

And of course [the STL file](https://web.archive.org/web/20150929120812if_/https://thingiverse-production-new.s3.amazonaws.com/zipfiles/6c/91/ab/f9/7c/LEGO_Mindstorms_RCX_NXT_EV3_fake_battery.zip) from [the archived version of the site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207195733/http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:122810).